# Laravel - Inicio de sesión con datos diferentes

Tags: laravel-5, login, autenticación, data

Tengo un controlador con inicio de sesion en laravel. Al paracer todo es correcto el usuario ingresa la contraseña y el email y se loguea, pero por algun motivo los datos en el Auth:user() no son los mismos del usuario que se logeo, es decir toma un registro random para llenar los datos. Dejo lo que tengo en mi controlador.

```
    $usuario=str_replace("-","",$request->usuario);
    $psw=str_replace("-","",$request->password);

    if (Auth::attempt(['usuario' => $usuario, 'password' => $psw])) {
        return redirect()->intended('admin/Usuarios');
    }
```

El proceso de logueo se hace correctamente pero los datos del usuario son erróneos, pertenecen a otro usuario. Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Puedes proporcionar más datos? El modelo de User, algunos datos de ejemplo y la configuración de auth.

Comment: Es un login sencillo, uso el modelo User por default, tengo diferentes usuario en la tabla creada con las migraciones tambien por default. Todo funciona correcto, las credenciales deben ser valida, etc. Pero cuando intento acceder al Auth::user()->nombre por ejemplo me da el nombre de otro usuario, y asi pasa con la mayoria, es lo raro, alguno usuario tienen correcto los datos y otros no.

Comment: Bueno, entonces no  "funciona correcto" si está entregando los datos que no son. La migración es la que trae Laravel por defecto? ¿qué versión exacta de Laravel usas?

Comment: Me refiero a que es correcto el proceso principal que es validar las credenciales, uso laravel 5.4 y la implementación es la que viene en la doc oficial.

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la pregunta y agregar los datos de la migración correspondiente?